# My reputation is now "object". I object

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow

When using Safari my reputation looks fine. But when using Chrome, viewing any of my answers/questions I see:

[image: badge]

Restarting Chrome did not fix it. I disabled my styles for SO, no luck. I'm on OS X 10.8.3 and Chrome 27.0.1448.0 dev.

Example (though I don't think anyone else can see it): [How do I make an editable DIV look like a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field)

Comment: Looks fine to me (no repro)...but that'd probably make a great avatar.

Comment: [SE officially supports current stable and current stable - 1 versions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), Chrome 27 dev isn't supported. But just in case, do you have any SE related extensions installed? If so, disable them and check again.

Comment: @Yannis Ah. That could be it. With as fast as Chrome releases, though, this could be in the stable version soon.

Comment: Probably you should report this to Chrome as a bug.

Comment: @Yannis I just have Stylish, which I disabled.

Comment: As Yannis said, we can't support beta browsers because 9 times of out 10 it's *their* bug, and one we shouldn't waste any time fruitlessly tracking down.  That being said, you should certainly report it to that browser's dev team before it hits release channel.